# How to start a new Django project

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, windows-7

**Environment:**

```
Windows 7
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Django==1.7.5
```

Whenever I try to create a new project:

```
python .\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject new_project,
```

I get this error:

```
python: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Where am I going wrong? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Do you have a file named `django-admin.py` under your <python install directory>\Scripts?

Comment: Why not using `django-admin.py startproject mysite`?

Comment: @Constantine - `django-admin.py startproject mysite` also doesn't work. I get a list of optional usage features: `Usage: django-admin.py subcommand [options] [args]`

Comment: @Selcuk - No I don't have that

Comment: I'm on linux, but I think the problem is that you did not add the django file path to your system path and it can not find the path to your script! As the error shows!

Comment: @user3663765 I don't think you installed Django correctly. You should try re-installing it using easy-install or pip and see what happens.

Comment: @user3663765 once you have django installed, try creating the project from the absolute path of `django-admin.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the system environment variables set up right (All the three below):

```
C:\Python34;
C:\Python34\Scripts;
C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\django\bin
```

then,

```
python .\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject new_project,
```

gives error:

```
python: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

since the command is system internally unrecognisable.

Instead, do:

```
django-admin startproject new_project
```

Note `django-admin` without `.py` extension

Read more at [Writing your first Django app, part 1¶](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, which I believe you are, leave off the .py on the django-admin.py. In other words, try django-admin startproject new_project.

Answer (score 0):

**Boilerplate Code**
To create django as well create django app you have to follow many common commands. for simplicity, kindly follow the below single-line commands separated by semicolon:

```
django-admin startproject project_name; cd project_name;python3 manage.py startapp app_name; cd app_name; mkdir templates
```

Those commands will create commonly used structure for django.